# Eclipse App Programming change the image of a Button?

Tags: android, m2eclipse

I am programming an app where after a certain time the designs of the buttons should change. So far so good, I have the designs already in Android and the buttons are already there, but I can't get it to change the design. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to ImageButtons?

Comment: No i use the normal buttons

Comment: And what must i do if i use image buttons?

Comment: I assume that you like to change the Button on click, isn't it?

Comment: it have a onclick listener